Connecting eigenfunctions in different regions
Imagine you have a function $V\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that around zero equals, let's say (just for simplicity) $$
V(x)=1 \quad \hbox{ for } \quad x\in(-1,1)
$$
and $$
V(x)=\dfrac{2}{x^2} \quad \hbox{ for } \quad \vert x\vert >100,
$$
and something else in between 1 and 100. Now consider the eigenvalue problem for $-\tfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$. For simplicity let's focus on the zero energy case. Due to the simplicity of $V(x)$ we could directly solve the problem around zero and for large $x$ separately, from where we would obtain  $$
y_1(x)=c_1e^x \quad \hbox{and} \quad y_2(x)=c_2e^{-x}
$$
for $x\in(-1,1)$ and $$
y_1(x)=c_1x^2 \quad \hbox{and} \quad y_2(x)=c_2\dfrac{1}{x}
$$
for $\vert x\vert>100$. Now, my question is, if I try to solve the problem in the whole line at once, is there any way I can ensure that, for example, the solution that is proportional to $e^x$ around zero is the one that becomes, say, proportional to $x^2$ for $\vert x\vert>100$ (or maybe to $1/x$)? Is there any way I can determine which solution around zero becomes which of the other solutions for $x$ large if we solve the problem in the whole line at once? I feel like there must be a simple argument for this but I can't see it right now. Does anybody know an argument for this?
Edit: I forgot to mention, here I'm thinking of the eigenvalue problem on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

I'm reasonably sure that the answer to the question you want to ask lies in WKB theory. As for the actual question, why should there be such a correspondence between solutions in the different regions? In a different basis I could write $y_1=\sinh(x)$ and $y_2=\cosh(x)$ for the inner solutions... in each region the solution is a linear combination
